# Submitting a question without beeing logged in - potential loss of data

Tags: bug

I experienced this issue after writing my question without beeing logged in. After hitting the 'Ask question' button, I was told that I am not logged in - so far so good. After logging in though, I wasn't redirected to my (still seemingly unsubmitted) question but rather I had to navigate to the question form by myself.

I was happy to see my work preserved - but hey, it was an old version of my text! Several refinements were lost and no tags attached either! I finally could work around this by stepping back in browser history and re-posting my question. But I think that is not how the process is intended to work, right? A user less savy or just beeing incautious could easily be fooled by this.

Thank you so much for your great work anyways!

Comment: It's not like it can save changes after every keystroke, that would be horribly resource consuming.  It can only make periodic draft saves.

Comment: @Servy: I believe that the OP (who hails from a non-English-speaking country) meant to say that he (she?) hit the **Post Your Question** button, and yet SO retained only a draft from a minute or three before.

Comment: @Servy: Yes indeed, my point was not that my question was'nt saved by the second but rather i could not post a question without beeing first logged in in a seamless manner.